# Slim redirect works; but also throws an exception

Tags: slim

The following code correctly redirects; but also throws an exception:

```
$app->post("/foo", function () use ($app) {

    try {

        $app->redirect('/bar');

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        $app->log->debug("\n" . $e->getFile() . " (Line " . $e->getLine() . ") " . " - " . strftime('%c') . ": Exception (" . $e->getMessage() . ")");
        $app->log->debug("\n" . $e->getTraceAsString());

    }

});
```

This is from the Slim log:

```
/{site root}/Slim/Slim.php (Line 1017)  - Wed Sep 17 17:51:33 2014: Exception ()

#0 /{site root}/Slim/Slim.php(1037): Slim\Slim->stop()
#1 /{site root}/Slim/Slim.php(1100): Slim\Slim->halt(302)
#2 /{site root}/index.php(328): Slim\Slim->redirect('/bar')
#3 [internal function]: {closure}()
#4 /{site root}/Slim/Route.php(462): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#5 /{site root}/Slim/Slim.php(1326): Slim\Route->dispatch()
#6 /{site root}/Slim/Middleware/Flash.php(85): Slim\Slim->call()
#7 /{site root}/Slim/Middleware/MethodOverride.php(92): Slim\Middleware\Flash->call()
#8 /{site root}/Slim/Middleware/PrettyExceptions.php(67): Slim\Middleware\MethodOverride->call()
#9 /{site root}/Slim/Slim.php(1271): Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions->call()
#10 /{site root}/index.php(689): Slim\Slim->run()
#11 {main}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Or is this a bug in Slim?  I can't find any mention of this particular issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slim uses exceptions for route helpers, redirect being one of them.  See the "[Route Helpers](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-Helpers)" section in the documentation:

> Please be aware that the following application instance method helpers
>   `halt()`, `pass()`, `redirect()` and `stop()` are implemented using
>   Exceptions. Each will throw a `\Slim\Exception\Stop` or
>   `\Slim\Exception\Pass` exception ... 
>   This behavior can be surprising if unexpected.

There are code samples showing the behavior you're experiencing and how to avoid it.  The trick is to redirect for error in the catch block and redirect for success after the try/catch block.

Comment: or, I suppose, test for \Slim\Exception\Pass in the catch block and use that for your success condition.

Comment: @HardlyNoticeable: You could test for the Slim exceptions, sure, but that feels wrong to me. I don't know that it's "wrong" to do that, but I never do. For what that's worth.

Comment: Route Helpers documentation is very clear about this topic: http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-Helpers